# Master/Detail flow: Possible to make some list items unclickable?

Tags: android, master-detail

I am using the Master/Detail flow application preset and I was wondering if I could set some items in the master list to be unclickable? I want to put headings for some list items that are grouped together, and these headings should be unclickable but I am not sure how to achieve that since the whole list is turned into clickable items.

ie,

```
Header 1
List item 1
List item 2
Header 2
List item 3
List item 4
```

etc where the header's are not clickable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement an override of `onEnabled()` in your `ListAdapter` and have it return false for the headers.

Comment: I used an array adapter so I can just subclass array adapter and override that method right?

Comment: Yes. Just subclass the adapter. But it sounds like your probably going to want more features that an ArrayAdapter can't do. So toy probably want to create your own extended BaseAdapter.